# jquery How to get string from the search box

Tags: jquery, search-box

I am studying jquery searching box.

I am getting trouble with getting string var from html.

in my html file.

i have..

```
<header>
  <div id="searchBox">
    <form name="searchForm">
      <div>
        <i class="icon-search icon-large icon-height"></i>
        <input name="searchfield" type="search" size="20" maxlength="30">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

and

in my jquery file i have

```
$(".icon-search").click(function() {
  var searchstring  = $(this).text('#searchfield');// $('#searchfield');
  searchstring.focus();
  //$('#searchBox').html($('input:searchfield').val());
  alert("searchfield.  " + searchstring +  " hahah");
});
```

when I clicked to searching some strings.

It shows that Object object instead of some strings.

I am not really sure how to convert object to strings.

Does anybody know how to convert it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This line of code means nothing:

```
var searchstring  = $(this).text('#searchfield');// $('#searchfield');
```

It should indeed be:

```
var searchstring = $('#searchfield');
```

Then you'll be able to do:

```
searchstring.focus();
```

And retreive the text with `.val()`:

```
alert("searchfield.  " + searchstring.val() +  " hahah");
```

`.text()` gets or sets the text content of a HTML element. It *gets* a value if it is being invoked without any parameters, and it *sets* a value if a value is passed to it. So `$(this).text('#searchfield')` would set the inner text of `$(this)` (your `.icon-search`) to the string `"#searchfield"`.

Now, a form element doesn't have an inner text, it has a *value*, hence `.val()`, which otherwise works the same way as `.text()`

```
alert(myTextbox.val()); // get value
myTextbox.val('test');  // set value
```

Edit:

Also, `$('#searchfield')` looks for an element of the ID "searchfield". You should either add `id="searchfield"` to your textfield, or update your script to

```
var searchstring = $('input[name=searchfield]');
```

Comment: i tried to apply ur way and it shows that undefined. what should i do :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code access the DOM object.

Try `$("#searchfield").attr('value')`

You can put any attribute you want in the attr() function and get it. To get its id just use 
`$("#searchfield").attr('id')`

Personally I use this a lot than `val()`, as it causes cross browser problems with some other DOM objects.

Comment: it is not working.  it shows undefined . Am i getting wrong data from html file ?

Comment: your html code needs fixing. type should be changed to 'text'. it should be <input id="searchfield" name="searchfield" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30">